# Cannot export list of customer from the grid magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer

when trying to export the list of customers i get this error Fatal error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory::argumentsResolver()
>   must be of the type array, null given, called in
>   /var/www/html/stfselecta/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php
>   on line 220 and defined in
>   /var/www/html/stfselecta/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:172
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/stfselecta/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(220):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->argumentsResolver('contact_person',
>   NULL) #1
>   /var/www/html/stfselecta/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Column.php(77):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('contact_person',
>   'varchar', Array) #2
>   /var/www/html/stfselecta/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/MassAction/Filter.php(182):
>   Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column->prepare() #3
>   /var/www/html/stfselecta/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/MassAction/Filter.php(180):
>   Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\F in
>   /var/www/html/stfselecta/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php
>   on line 172.

I also want to know how to hide some attributes to be diplayed in the list for example i don't want to find the id or the name of customer in my csv file so hwo to do that what do i have to override exactly thanks in advance

Comment: Does any custom attribute show into grid?

Comment: yes  i have added 5 and i can see them all

Comment: Kindly first remove that and then try? I think issue is related to that.

Comment: do you mean that i have to delete the 5 custom attributes that i had added

Comment: no first just remove from column and then check.

Comment: yes i checked that and the same got same error